# Need a way to evenly distribute a set number of items to a set number of things

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I am working on a rationing like system in python where there are locations in need of these rations and when we get a shipment it is evenly distributed to all the locations. that's relatively easy the hard part is when the shipment (commit) does not evenly divide by the number of locations, I am unsure how to do this.

```
ration = commit/len(indiv_list)
if commit % len(indiv_list) == 0:
    print("perfect match no remainder")
    add1 = False
    for _ in ration:
        for loc in indiv_list:
            q = Orders.query.filter_by(ordered_by=loc, order=type).first()
            if q.amount == 0:
                add1 = True
                break
            newOrder = ClaimedOrders(ordered_by=loc, status=0, claimed_by=supplier, order=type)
            q.amount -= 1
            db.session.add(newOrder)
            if add1:
                if q.amount == 0:
                    break
                else:
                    newOrder2 = ClaimedOrders(ordered_by=loc, status=0, claimed_by=supplier, order=type)
                    q.amount -= 1
                    db.session.add(newOrder2)
                    add = False
        db.session.commit()

else:
    pass
```

any help would be very much appreciated. by the way, this is running in a flask app

Comment: So how do you want to handle the case when the shipment does not evenly divide by the number of locations? What happens to the extra items, are they returned to the sender? Are they sent to one special location? Are they distributed among the locations you have?

Comment: they should be distributed as evenly as possible to the locations

Comment: Let's say there are 7 locations and 4 items - what does "as evenly as possible" mean? Can you divide a shipment into pieces?

Comment: no, the 4 items would just go to the first 4 locations

Comment: It's unclear what trouble you're having. Can you edit your question and add some examples?

Comment: Do you want to keep track of who got extra rations this time so they get less next time?  Or is it sufficient to hand out extra rations randomly so that it averages out over time?  Those are the two main strategies to follow.